# pull individual values from a string and count

Tags: javascript

I want to type text into the input field, click submit and sort out vowels only.  Then I want to show the # of vowels below the input field.

So far I've managed to print what the user types into the field as a substring to separate the letters.  I'm hoping someone could help me with a little direction/suggestions from here.

Thanks!

```js
function myReverse() {
   var hello = document.getElementById("countVowels").value;
   var inputAnswer = hello.substring(-3);
   document.getElementById("numVowels").innerHTML = inputAnswer;
}
```

```html
<form id="myVowels">
<input type="text" id="countVowels"  name="countVowels" />
</form>
<button onclick="myReverse()">Vowel counter</button>
<p id="numVowels"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you define vowels, you should be able to do that pretty easily with a regex. Remove everything but vowels and check the length of the string. If you want unique counts, or counts per-vowel, that can be done as well.

```js
function myReverse() {
  var input = document.getElementById("countVowels").value;

  var lower = input.toLowerCase();
  var vowels = lower.replace(/[^aeiou]/g, "");

  document.getElementById("numVowels").textContent = "Input has " + vowels.length + " vowels.";

  // Count appearances of each vowel
  var vowelCounts = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; ++i) {
    var current = vowels[i];
    vowelCounts[current] = (vowelCounts[current] || 0) + 1;
  }

  document.getElementById("vowelCounts").textContent = JSON.stringify(vowelCounts);

  // Show unique counts
  // If you have a modern browser, you can use Object.keys(vowelCounts), otherwise:
  var counter = 0;
  for (var f in vowelCounts) {
    if (vowelCounts.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
      ++counter;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("uniqueVowels").textContent = "Input has " + counter + " unique vowels.";
}
```

```html
<form id="myVowels">
  <input type="text" id="countVowels" name="countVowels" />
</form>
<button onclick="myReverse()">Vowel counter</button>
<p id="numVowels"></p>
<pre id="vowelCounts"></pre>
<p id="uniqueVowels"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!  I was so stuck!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for (if I understood your question right):

```
function myReverse() {
        var hello = document.getElementById("countVowels").value,
            vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'],
            inputAnswer = [];

        for(var i = 0; i<vowels.length; i++) {
            if(hello.split(vowels[i]).length > 1) {
                inputAnswer.push(vowels[i]+': '+hello.split(vowels[i]).length);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("numVowels").innerHTML = inputAnswer.join(', ');
    }
```

and here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y1usvehg/